# Is there a way to stop mobs pick up blocks mod for Forge/FTB

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-forge

On my multiplayer server some players don't like that zombies and other NPCs are stealing their dropped items.

I know I can change the gamerule "mobGriefing" to false, but that will stop Creepers from destroying everything and that's lame ;)

How can I prevent mobs from stealing dropped items without preventing creepers from destroying blocks? Maybe there's a mod for this?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms to be fair, the main part of the question is about asking how to do this in game so isn't off topic.  If the answer is "no, there isn't a way to do this in game, so you will need to find a mod (which we can't help you with)" then that is a perfectly good question.

Comment: @franglais Well, now that it's been edited, I regret flagging it for that reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an NBTeditor to change the value of CanPickUpLoot on various mobs to false, this is how i managed it but you need to have access to the server files,

I have spent the last 6 months looking for a simpler solution with no luck. from what i can tell the only other option is Mobgriefing Rule. or if this is caused when the player dies and the players are getting annoyed at loosing their items you can set keepinventory to true. but that would be a community decision. as many players don't like that rule.

Comment: Mmh this is only for spawned NPCs or? So everytime a new zombie spawned, i've to stop the server and change the chunk settings?

Comment: pretty much, it wasn't an issue for me because i was only playing with 3 other people and so if someone died we were able to do that pretty quickly.

Comment: In the end It is just part of the game. you and your friends need to decide whether they can accept that or whether you want to turn off all griefing, Or make a request on the MC Forum for a mod that can do what you need. but nothing exists atm

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want mobs moving or breaking blocks do /gamerule mobgriefing false

Answer (score -2):

The most annoying thing, steeling dropped items after death, is now prevanted with an Gravestone Mod, there are many out there.

If somebody has the same problem, use a gravestone mod and the items will be stored into a gravestone and no